# set mouse cursor position as objects heading

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, mouse, turtle-graphics

I want to set object `u1`'s heading by the mouse cursors position inside the window.

```
import turtle
import pygame
import time

win = turtle.Screen()#window
win.title("eagle.py")
win.setup(1920,1080)
win.bgcolor("black")
win.bgpic("triangle")


c1 = turtle.Turtle()#cloud1
c1.speed(0)
c1.penup()
c1.setposition(-1075, 256)
c1.color("white")
c1.shape("triangle")
c_speed = 1 #cloudspeed

u1 = turtle.Turtle()#user1
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
u1.shape("triangle")
u1.color("red")
u1.speed(0)
u1.setposition(0,0)
u1.setheading(mouse_pos)
u1.penup()
u_speed = 10 #playerspeed


def u1_r():
    x = u1.xcor()
    x += u_speed
    u1.setx(x)
def u1_l():
    x = u1.xcor()
    x -= u_speed
    u1.setx(x)
def u1_up():
    y = u1.ycor()
    y += u_speed
    u1.sety(y)
def u1_down():
    y = u1.ycor()
    y -= u_speed
    u1.sety(y)


while True:
    win.update()
    time.sleep(1/160)
    c1.setx(c1.xcor() + c_speed)
    if c1.xcor() > 1075:
        c1.goto(-1075, 256)
    win.listen()
    win.onkeypress(u1_r, "d")
    win.onkeypress(u1_l, "a")
    win.onkeypress(u1_up, "w")
    win.onkeypress(u1_down, "s")
```

The program keeps shutting down immediately after running. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have the following:

```
win.listen()
win.onkeypress(u1_r, "d")
win.onkeypress(u1_l, "a")
win.onkeypress(u1_up, "w")
win.onkeypress(u1_down, "s")
```

inside a loop indicates that you don't have a basic understanding of the environment in which you're working.  Let's start over, tossing **pygame** and **time** and just work within the **turtle** framework:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def player_r():
    player.setheading(0)
    player.setx(player.xcor() + player_speed)

def player_l():
    player.setheading(180)
    player.setx(player.xcor() - player_speed)

def player_up():
    player.setheading(90)
    player.sety(player.ycor() + player_speed)

def player_down():
    player.setheading(270)
    player.sety(player.ycor() - player_speed)

def move():
    cloud.setx(cloud.xcor() + cloud_speed)

    if cloud.xcor() > 940:
        cloud.goto(-940, 256)

    screen.update()

    screen.ontimer(move)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1920, 1080)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.tracer(False)

cloud = Turtle()
cloud.shape('circle')
cloud.shapesize(1, 3)
cloud.color('white')

cloud.penup()
cloud.setposition(-940, 256)

cloud_speed = 1

player = Turtle()
player.shape('turtle')
player.color('red')

player.penup()

player_speed = 10

screen.onkeypress(player_r, 'd')
screen.onkeypress(player_l, 'a')
screen.onkeypress(player_up, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(player_down, 's')
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code,  string is in heading. Instead, put variable.

```
u1 = turtle.Turtle()
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
u1.heading(mouse_pos)  # variable
```

**Edit:** This worked for me, triangle moving..

It seems `pygame.init()` is need at first.

`u1.setheading` has a number inside, not tuple. This is for angle. [(man turtle)](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/turtle.html#turtle.setheading)

```
import turtle
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

win = turtle.Screen()#window
win.title("eagle.py")
win.setup(1920,1080)
win.bgcolor("black")
win.bgpic() # changed


c1 = turtle.Turtle()#cloud1
c1.speed(0)
c1.penup()
c1.setposition(-1075, 256)
c1.color("white")
c1.shape("triangle")
c_speed = 1 #cloudspeed

u1 = turtle.Turtle()#user1
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
u1.shape("triangle")
u1.color("red")
u1.speed(0)
u1.setposition(0,0)
u1.setheading(0)  # to be changed, setheading(int)
u1.penup()
u_speed = 10 #playerspeed


def u1_r():
    x = u1.xcor()
    x += u_speed
    u1.setx(x)
def u1_l():
    x = u1.xcor()
    x -= u_speed
    u1.setx(x)
def u1_up():
    y = u1.ycor()
    y += u_speed
    u1.sety(y)
def u1_down():
    y = u1.ycor()
    y -= u_speed
    u1.sety(y)


while True:
    win.update()
    time.sleep(1/160)
    c1.setx(c1.xcor() + c_speed)
    if c1.xcor() > 1075:
        c1.goto(-1075, 256)
    win.listen()
    win.onkeypress(u1_r, "d")
    win.onkeypress(u1_l, "a")
    win.onkeypress(u1_up, "w")
    win.onkeypress(u1_down, "s")
```

Comment: I've changed it to 
`u1 = turtle.Turtle()
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
u1.setheading(mouse_pos)`
but it still crashes

Comment: sure, but I know that the error is ocurring in `pygame.mouse.get_pos`

Comment: I have made something that works and edited my answer. Please try.

Answer (score 1):

`turtle.heading()` expects a numeric argument specifying the heading in degrees.

I don't think you can use the `pygame` and `turtle` modules at the same time. Both have their own way of drawing graphics and getting the mouse's current position, so theoretically you can use either.

Regardless, of which one you're using, you'll need to compute the heading's angle from the mouse's x, y position.

Here's how to measure the angle to the origin of an x, y position (assuming its x value isn't zero):

```
import math

x, y = ... # Mouse position.
print(math.degrees(math.atan(y/x)))
```